# How could I know how much time it takes to query items in a table of MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

Our website has a problem: The visiting time of one page is too long. We have found out that it has a n*n matrix in that page; and for each item in the matrix, it queries three tables from MYSQL database. Every item in that matrix do the query quiet alike.

So I wonder maybe it is the large amount of MYSQL queries lead to the problem. And I want to try to fix it. Here is one of my confusions I list below:

1.

```
m = store.execute('SELECT X FROM TABLE1 WHERE I=1')
result = store.execute('SELECT Y FROM TABLE2 WHERE X in m')
```

2.

```
r = store.execute('SELECT X, Y FROM TABLE2');
result = []
for each in r:
    i = store.execute('SELECT I FROM TABLE1 WHERE X=%s', each[0])
    if i[0][0]=1:
        result.append(each)
```

It got about 200 items in TABLE1 and more then 400 items in TABLE2. I don't know witch part takes the most time, so I can't make a better decision of how to write my sql statement.

How could I know how much time it takes to do some operation in MYSQL? Thank you!

Comment: Look up explain (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see what is going on and what indexes are being  used (if any).

Comment: Is it possible to tag this in the language used here? It's not clear from this example.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than installing a bunch of special tools, you could take a dead-simple approach like this (pardon my Ruby):

```
start = Time.new
# DB query here
puts "Query XYZ took #{Time.now - start} sec"
```

Hopefully you can translate that to Python. OR... pardon my Ruby again...

```
QUERY_TIMES = {}
def query(sql)
  start = Time.new
  connection.execute(sql)
  elapsed = Time.new - start
  QUERY_TIMES[sql] ||= []
  QUERY_TIMES[sql] << elapsed
end
```

Then run all your queries through this custom method. After doing a test run, you can make it print out the number of times each query was run, and the average/total execution times.

For the future, plan to spend some time learning about "profilers" (if you haven't already). Get a good one for your chosen platform, and spend a little time learning how to use it well.

Answer (score 0):

I use the MySQL Workbench for SQL development.  It gives response times and can connect remotely to MySQL servers granted you have the permission (which in this case will give you a more accurate reading).

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Also, as you've realized it appears you have a SQL statement in a for loop.  That could drastically effect performance.  You'll want to take a different route with retrieving that data.